# Get a List of All Valid Fields in Google CL Picasa

Tags: command-line, picasa-web

I want to get the url to the images on Picasa such as:

```
https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-rU35o4QG9eU/Tyrl8TnswSI/AAAAAAAADus/VCI1SAKi1tc/s800/1027-skype-ingilizce-alistirma.jpg
```

I use the following command:

```
picasa list --fields url
```

This command gives the url to the web page that contains the image such as:

```
https://picasaweb.google.com/beskurusafoto/Colors#5619859775100257794
```

Is there a way to get a list of all valid fields so I can find out the urls to the images?

Answer (score 3):

google picasa list --fields url_download ALBUM_NAME

I needed the same thing, so I read through the python source.
This gives you a list of URLs that you can wget.